# How to find pixel in image using Imagick

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

[image]

This is my first demo and the code is shown below.

```
<?php

     $overlay = new \Imagick( realpath ("c:/wamp64/www/photo_effect/photos/3809.jpg" ) );
     $imagick = new \Imagick( realpath ( "c:/wamp64/www/photo_effect/photos/overly.png" ) );

     $overlay->setImageVirtualPixelMethod ( \Imagick::VIRTUALPIXELMETHOD_TRANSPARENT );

     $width = $overlay->getImageWidth ();
     $height = $overlay->getImageHeight ();

     $offset = 332.9;

     $points = array (
           0 ,0 ,364,51 ,
           $width ,0 ,473.4 ,23 ,
           0 ,$height ,433.5  ,182 ,
           $width ,$height ,523  ,119.4
      );

     //$overlay->modulateImage (97,100,0);
     $overlay->distortImage ( \Imagick::DISTORTION_PERSPECTIVE ,$points ,true );

     $imagick->compositeImage ( $overlay ,\Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER ,364.5 - $offset ,23.5 );

     $imagick->writeImage ( "c:/wamp64/www/photo_effect/uploads/real.jpg" );

?>
```

> When I use another image, it does not fit in this frame background image.

[image]

> This is my demo

[image]

```
<?php

    $overlay = new \Imagick( realpath ( "c:/wamp64/www/photo_effect/photos/3809.jpg" ) );
    $imagick = new \Imagick( realpath ( "c:/wamp64/www/photo_effect/photos/Frame.png" ) );

    $overlay->setImageVirtualPixelMethod ( \Imagick::VIRTUALPIXELMETHOD_TRANSPARENT );

    $width = $overlay->getImageWidth ();
    $height = $overlay->getImageHeight ();

    //$offset = 100.9;

    $points = array (
         0 ,0 ,364,51 ,
         $width ,0 ,473.4 ,23 ,
         0 ,$height ,200,349 ,
         $width ,$height ,714,349
    );

   //$overlay->modulateImage (97,100,0);
   $overlay->distortImage ( \Imagick::DISTORTION_PERSPECTIVE ,$points ,true );

   $imagick->compositeImage ( $overlay ,\Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER ,364.5 ,23.5 );

   $imagick->writeImage ("c:/wamp64/www/photo_effect/uploads/success.jpg" );

 ?>
```

> So, how do I find the proper pixel coordinates in the two images. And how do I composite both images. Also how do I rotate the image in PHP-Imagick

Comment: You may have your points in the wrong order. In command line ImageMagick, you need to alternate input, output with corresponding points, so  i1x,i1y o1x,o1y  i2x,i2y o2x,o2y ...

Comment: Which is right points ??

Comment: You need to alternate input, output with corresponding points, so i1x,i1y o1x,o1y i2x,i2y o2x,o2y ...  Where i is input and o is output